# Hausdorff space and disjoint open sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $x_1,...,x_n$ points of $X$. Then there exist open pairwise disjoint sets $V_1,...,V_n$ such that $x_i$ is in $V_i$ for every $i$.

How can I prove this?

Comment: That's the definition of a Hausdorff space.

Comment: No, it is only if $n=2$.

Comment: Yes, but think about this. For any two points you can find $V_i$ and $V_j$ disjoint containing $x_i$ and $x_j$, respectively. What property of open sets can you use to ensure the $V_i$ you pick is the right one?

Answer (score 4):

You know that each pair $i \neq j$ there are open sets $V_{ij}$ and $V_{ji}$ so that $x_i \in V_{ij}$ and $x_j \in V_{ji}$ and $x_i \notin V_{ji}, x_j \notin V_{ij}$.  For convenience of notation, define $V_{ii} = X$.

Now consider the intersection $U_i = \bigcap_{j=1}^n V_{ij}$.  This set is open (why?) and non-empty (why?) and contains $x_i$ but not $x_j$ for any $j \neq i$.